# Scrapy-Splash ERROR 400: "description": "Required argument is missing: url"

Tags: python, error-handling, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm using scrapy splash in my code to generate javascript-html codes.

And splash is giving me back this render.html

```
{
    "error": 400,
    "type": "BadOption",
    "description": "Incorrect HTTP API arguments",
    "info": {
        "type": "argument_required",
        "argument": "url",
        "description": "Required argument is missing: url"
    }
}
```

And I can't get a response with the javascript generated html.
This is my spider.py

```
class ThespiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'thespider'
    #allowed_domains = ['https://www.empresia.es/empresa/repsol/']
    start_urls = ['https://www.empresia.es/empresa/repsol/']

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request( 'http://example.com', self.fake_start_requests )

    def fake_start_requests(self, response):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest( url, self.parse,
                                 args={'wait': 1.5, 'http_method': 'POST'},
                                 endpoint='render.html'
                                 )

    def parse(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)
        title = response.css("title").extract()
        # har = response.data["har"]["log"]["pages"]
        headers = response.headers.get('Content-Type')
        names = response.css('.fa-user-circle-o+ a::text').extract()
        yield {
            'title': title,
            #'har': har,
            'headers': headers,
            'names': names,
            'length': len(names)
        }
```

and this is my settings.py

```
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

# Splash Settings
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    # Engine side
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
    # Downloader side
}

SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
}
SPLASH_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8050/'
# SPLASH_URL = 'http://192.168.59.103:8050/'
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It looks like the API you are interacting with isn't getting something it expects. Do you have documentation or source code for the API?

Comment: This is the documentation for the API - https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html

I can't seem to figure out what I missed.

Comment: Hi, i am getting the same error, did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Provide the `url` parameter in `args` parameter and it will work.

```
yield SplashRequest(self.parse,
                     args={'url': url, 'wait': 1.5, 'http_method': 'POST'},
                     endpoint='render.html'
                     )
```